# geom_tile outputs are coloured lines instead of coloured grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heat map using `ggplot2` in R.

I want to illustrate the percentage of sport practice as a function of age (50 to 95 years) and a continuous 5-point scale.

However, instead of outputting a grid with a specific color for each cell, R outputs a color only for each line.

If somebody could give me a tip to get a grid instead of lines, I would really appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXL6K.png)Here is the script I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# data
plotpercent0 <- matrix(c(15.25,22.73,20.97,13.43,12.63,13.85,11.46,17.14,14.44,16.09,18.81,21.25,11.9,16.46,14.75,12.99,15.94,19.44,17.86,22.03,25,17.86,30.61,23.68,25,13.89,33.33,21.21,32.35,41.38,46.43,30.3,46.67,23.53,14.29,35.71,27.27,40,42.86,50,50,0,50,100,0,100,15.25,22.73,20.97,13.43,12.63,13.85,11.46,17.14,14.44,16.09,18.81,21.25,11.9,16.46,14.75,12.99,15.94,19.44,17.86,22.03,25,17.86,30.61,23.68,25,13.89,33.33,21.21,32.35,41.38,46.43,30.3,46.67,23.53,14.29,35.71,27.27,40,42.86,50,50,0,50,100,0,100,15.25,22.73,20.97,13.43,12.63,13.85,11.46,17.14,14.44,16.09,18.81,21.25,11.9,16.46,14.75,12.99,15.94,19.44,17.86,22.03,25,17.86,30.61,23.68,25,13.89,33.33,21.21,32.35,41.38,46.43,30.3,46.67,23.53,14.29,35.71,27.27,40,42.86,50,50,0,50,100,0,100,15.25,22.73,20.97,13.43,12.63,13.85,11.46,17.14,14.44,16.09,18.81,21.25,11.9,16.46,14.75,12.99,15.94,19.44,17.86,22.03,25,17.86,30.61,23.68,25,13.89,33.33,21.21,32.35,41.38,46.43,30.3,46.67,23.53,14.29,35.71,27.27,40,42.86,50,50,0,50,100,0,100,15.25,22.73,20.97,13.43,12.63,13.85,11.46,17.14,14.44,16.09,18.81,21.25,11.9,16.46,14.75,12.99,15.94,19.44,17.86,22.03,25,17.86,30.61,23.68,25,13.89,33.33,21.21,32.35,41.38,46.43,30.3,46.67,23.53,14.29,35.71,27.27,40,42.86,50,50,0,50,100,0,100), nrow=5, ncol=46, byrow = T)
plopercent0 = as.numeric (plotpercent0)
colnames(plotpercent0) <- c(50:95) 
rownames(plotpercent0) <- c("CSC1","CSC2","CSC3","CSC4","CSC5")
melted_plotpercent1 <- melt(plotpercent0)
melted_plotpercent1
colnames(melted_plotpercent1) <- c("CSC", "Age", "per")

# plot
output_plotpercent1 <- ggplot(melted_plotpercent1, aes(CSC, Age)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = per), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient (low = "yellow", high = "red") 
output_plotpercent1
```

Comment: It's because the data you passed has the same value for each 'row' (=Age). This data produces this plot.

Comment: Looking at `plotpercent0` makes this fairly obvious.

Comment: yes, thanks GGamba and Axeman. There is indeed a problem in the raw data. Thanks again. M